# Qt Creator ROS plugin installation error

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, qtcreator, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All

I'm trying to install Qt Creator Ros plugin, but get the following error.

> nvidia@tegra-ubuntu:~/Downloads$ chmod
> > +x qtcreator-ros-xenial-latest-online-installer.run
> > 
> > nvidia@tegra-ubuntu:~/Downloads$ sudo
> ./qtcreator-ros-xenial-latest-online-installer.run
>
> nvidia@tegra-ubuntu:~/Downloads$ sudo
> > ./qtcreator-ros-xenial-latest-online-installer.run
> > ./qtcreator-ros-xenial-latest-online-installer.run:
> > 1:
> > ./qtcreator-ros-xenial-latest-online-installer.run:
> > ELF: not found
> > ./qtcreator-ros-xenial-latest-online-installer.run:
> > 2:
> > ./qtcreator-ros-xenial-latest-online-installer.run:
> > Syntax error: ")" unexpected
> > 
> > nvidia@tegra-ubuntu:~/Downloads$ qmake
> --version QMake version 3.0
>
> Using Qt version 5.5.1 in
> /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu

I'm trying to install it on a Jetson Tx2 running ubuntu 16.04. Current version of qt creator is 5.5.1 and QMake version 3.0. ROS installation is kinetic.
What can I do wrong. I'm following this:

https://ros-qtc-plugin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_source/How-to-Install-Users.html

using the Xenial installer.

Thanks in advance

/Esben

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312813/qt-creator-ros-plugin-installation-error/) by [ebachs10](https://answers.ros.org/users/39482/ebachs10/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-01-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ELF: not found (cut) Syntax error: ")" unexpected

This may be a typical error when platform a binary is built for is not what you're running on (e.g. [ref on unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336436/syntax-error-unexpected-when-execute-a-compiled-c-program)). My guess is you're getting that error because you're on Jetson Tx2, which is ARM-based IIRC and I doubt QtCreator's binary is built for.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2019-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ebachs10](https://answers.ros.org/users/39482/ebachs10/) on 2019-01-15**:
Thank you very much for the quick answer - I'm pretty new into this, so a can not see through all the time ;) I believe it because of the Jetson, based on your answer.